# safari copy only plain link

Tags: safari, copy-paste, url, links

I'm copying a link from Safari, via "Copy Image Link". When I'm pasting it to some places, like Messages.app, or some input fields on the Web (not every one, but many of them), I just get a file-name:

[image]

[image]

(The latter sends a clickable filename on Computers, however it's just plain filename, not clickable, on iPhones :-( )

Can I just disable this nurturing behaviour and get raw, plain links? They are fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the screenshot, I noticed that you are pasting it into Messages.app. What I'll usually do to work around this annoyance is to paste using `Option+Shift+Command+V`. This works for most apps that takes more than just plain text input.

Comment: oh, that works! maybe I should swap these shortcuts around